# How are the points calculated?

Tags: support, reputation, daily-reputation-limit

Usually my answer are modest and only get

- +10 for each upvote
- +15 for accepted answer

But today I got lots of upvotes on my answer and "Nice answer" badge, but the sum doesnt match. Shouldnt I get +145 points [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40679208/count-includes-null-values/40679371#40679371)?

[image]

Comment: Looks like 12 upvotes today and an accept mark with the other vote from a previous day.

Comment: You totalled 275 today, I guess you hit the rep cap.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You hit the daily reputation cap, so you didn't receive any reputation for the last vote on that answer. See [What is the daily reputation cap and how can I hit it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/32160/310998) on Meta Stack Exchange:

> The maximum amount of reputation you can earn *in one day* from upvotes and approved suggested edits is 200.  Any *upvotes* you receive after reaching that number no longer award any points.

Comment: accepted answer doesnt go into the limit isnt? I guess that is how I went over 200 to 275?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza The reputation you get from having your answer accepted is not counted in the daily limit. You have 5 answers accepted today, and 5 * 15 = 75.

Comment: Maybe I shouldnt look depth, but is there a way to know how many point over the cap lost today?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza There's no built-in way to check this, but you can write a query in the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/).